# Command to display evictions graph in maven similar to SBT

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

SBT for scala has command  `sbt evicted` that displays the transitive dependency graph with evicted versions. something similar to [this](https://github.com/sclasen/akka-zk-cluster-seed/issues/29#issue-292028766).

Is there any similar option that is provided maven?